# How accurate is coincidence counting, and how do we know?

Tags: experimental-physics, photonics, experimental-technology

Experiments that feature the creation of entangled photons through SPDC often make use of coincidence counters. How can one photon be accurately correlated with its entangled partner by a coincidence counter? Are there any methods or technologies that help decrease the error of coincidence counting methods that help validate the trust in their accuracy that so many experiments depend on?